# OpenId 2.0: session type vs. association type

Tags: openid, diffie-hellman, openid-provider

The [OpenID 2.0 specification](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html) says very little about the relation between the session type and association type in OpenID association requests.  My questions: (1) Is a combination of session type "DH-SHA1" and association type "HMAC-SHA256" valid?  (2) How about the reverse, i.e. "DH-SHA256" and "HMAC-SHA1"?

I don't think these mixed combinations are explicitly forbidden by the spec, but section 8.2.3 describes the process of encrypting the MAC key for transport as follows:

```
enc_mac_key

     Value: base64(H(btwoc(g ^ (xa * xb) mod p)) XOR MAC key)

     Description: The MAC key (shared secret), encrypted with the
     secret Diffie-Hellman value.  H is either "SHA1" or "SHA256"
     depending on the session type.
```

Does this imply that the MAC key length must be 20 bytes for session type DH-SHA1 and 32 byte for session type DH-SHA256?  Section 6.2 of the spec states

```
OpenID Authentication supports two signature algorithms:
o  HMAC-SHA1 - 160 bit key length ([RFC2104] and [RFC3174])
o  HMAC-SHA256 - 256 bit key length ([RFC2104] and [FIPS180-2]
```

Does this then imply that DH-SHA1 always must be paired with HMAC-SHA1 and the same for the ...256 versions?

Another data point: the OpenId provider at https://me.yahoo.com/ seems to accept association requests with session type DH-SHA1 and association type HMAC-SHA256, returning a 20 byte MAC key.

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? My gut would say the combinations you specified aren't explicitly forbidden, the same conclusion you came to. Have you tried StackOverflow's OpenID provider?

Comment: @NeilC.Obremski no, I didn't find anybody who knew and then got distracted by other things.  Still would be happy to receive an answer on this question.

Comment: I hear you. I'm building something currently and if I come up with a definitive answer, I'll post it here. I understand about getting distracted though!